# How to show a div if length of particular class is empty or zero in angular js

Tags: angularjs

These divs are generated dynamically.I add a class `boxselected` on click of the div and I want to show an error message  when `boxselected`  class length is zero.

```
<div class="boxSearch" ng-click="onClickTitles($event)" 
   ng-repeat="title in PatientTitles" data-key="{{ title.ID }}">
 {{ title.Salutation }}
</div>
```

Comment: Can you post a click event?

Comment: sir, satisfied your answer but i want to do like we can do in jquery $(''.boxSearch .boxSelected).length

Comment: If you post the `onclick` event of the code that would give you a good quality code from us?

Comment: @RamawatarSharma Please see the below answer, if you want that in jquery then hasclass method will be sufficient.

Comment: This is my onclick code  $scope.onClickTitles = function ($event) {
            var obj = $event.currentTarget;
            if ($(obj).hasClass('boxSelected')) {
                $(obj).removeClass('boxSelected');
            }
            else {
                $('#tdTitle .boxSearch').removeClass('boxSelected');
                $(obj).addClass('boxSelected');
            }
        }

Answer (score -1):

If you are using angular 1.x

```
var myElement = angular.element(document.getElementById('someelement'));
   if(myElement.hasClass('someclass')){
    //show error
      }
```

Comment: any reasons for negative votes?? community where i am wrong??

Comment: I didn't down vote you, but perhaps the reason is because you're not using angular.element efficiently. You could simplify it to be:
if(angular.element('#someelement').hasClass('someclass')){...}